# HAPI FHIR Client - Patient data retrieving from public test server

Tags: java, spring, jackson, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

Ні! I am trying to retrieving patient data from test server (https://api.logicahealth.org/DVJan21CnthnPDex/open)
If i log response like that

```
log.info("Returning: {}", client.getFhirContext().newJsonParser().setPrettyPrint(true).encodeToString(patient));
```

i get json what i need,

```
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"smart-1032702","meta":{"versionId":"1","lastUpdated":"2020-07-15T02:51:25.000+00:00","source":"#KQSArAdbxORTtqVw"},"text":{"status":"generated","div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Amy Shaw</div>"},"identifier":[{"use":"official","type":{"coding":[{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203","code":"MR","display":"Medical Record Number"}],"text":"Medical Record Number"},"system":"http://hospital.smarthealthit.org","value":"smart-1032702"}],"active":true,"name":[{"use":"official","family":"Shaw","given":["Amy","V"]}],"telecom":[{"system":"phone","value":"800-782-6765","use":"mobile"},{"system":"email","value":"amy.shaw@example.com"}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"2007-03-20","address":[{"use":"home","line":["49 Meadow St"],"city":"Mounds","state":"OK","postalCode":"74047","country":"USA"}],"generalPractitioner":[{"reference":"Practitioner/smart-Practitioner-72004454"}]}
```

but if i try to return patient object in mvc controller

```
    Bundle bundle =
            client.search()
                    .forResource(Patient.class)
                    .where(Patient.IDENTIFIER.exactly().identifier("smart-1032702"))
                    .returnBundle(Bundle.class)
                    .execute();

    Patient patient = (Patient) bundle.getEntry().get(0).getResource();
    log.info("Returning: {}", client.getFhirContext().newJsonParser().setPrettyPrint(true).encodeToString(patient));
    return patient;
```

i receive in browser 404 entity-not-found. I also create message converters like this

```
@Bean
public IGenericClient fhirClient() {
    IGenericClient client = FhirContext.forR4().newRestfulGenericClient(base);
    client.getFhirContext().registerCustomType(Patient.class);
    return client;
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
    messageConverters.add(converter());
    messageConverters.add(hapiMessageConverter());
    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    MediaType fhir = new MediaType("application", "json+fhir");
    List<MediaType> jacksonTypes = new ArrayList<>(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
    jacksonTypes.add(fhir);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(jacksonTypes);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public HapiHttpMessageConverter hapiMessageConverter() {
    return new HapiHttpMessageConverter();
}

@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
    messageConverters.add(0, hapiMessageConverter());
}`
```

How to convert fhir resources to json via converter bean? Who can tell what i do wrong?
Thenks for any reply!

Answer (score 1):

Your search is looking at Patients with Patient.identifier matching your value. This looks at the list of business identifiers that are part of the Patient data, instead of looking at the Patient.id field which contains the technical identity. You will probably get better results when you change your `where` clause to:

```
.where(Patient.RES_ID.matches().value("smart-1032702"))
```

Or you could do a `read` instead of a `search`, if you're using only the technical identity anyway. Then, instead of the Bundle you'll get your Patient object right away.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I try read() instead of search() and another query criterion but it still returns an empty object with 404 status in controller. Most likely mvc beans configuration is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, that could be, but I do not know enough about that to help you with that...